# Python Regex to match a string with single whitespace between two words with last word is fixed

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to Python regex and struggling to come up with a regex that can match the a strings with a single whitespace between two words with the last word being fixed.

For Example:

- "MPMIDEMA Index"
- "cpmindx Index"

The first 'word' in the string can be in either lowercase or uppercase letters but the last word in the string will always be fixed which is 'Index'.

I've got the code below but it doesn't seem to work:

```
txt = "jjj Index"
x = re.search("\s.Index", txt)
```

Comment: What were you going for with `\s.`?

Comment: What do you expect as outcome?

Comment: You say that the string contains two words. If you know that the second word is irrelevant then txt.split()[0] will give you what you need. If you need to check the second word then assert txt.split()[1] == 'Index'. RE is overkill for this

Answer (score 0):

You need a lookead assertion to extract a word followed by 'Index'.

> (?=...)
>
> Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

```
text = 'blah blah blah cpmindx Index blah blah blah'

out = re.findall(r'(\w+)(?= Index)', text)
```

```
>>> out
['cpmindx']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

pattern = "^(?:[a-z]+|[A-Z]+) Index$"

text = ["MPMIDEMA Index", "cpmindx Index"]

for txt in text:
    if re.match(pattern, txt):
        print(txt, "is matched")
```

output:

```
MPMIDEMA Index is matched
cpmindx Index is matched
```